# Order of partial sums in the derivatives of the Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given periodic function $f\in C^{w}[0,1]$ with its Fourier series
$f(x)=\sum\limits_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}f_{s}\exp(2\pi isx)$. What can one
say about the asymptotic order of

$$\sum_{s=-K}^{K}\left(\frac{s}{K}\right)^{q}f_{s}\exp(2\pi isx)$$ for $q>w$
and $K\rightarrow\infty$? Is it just a constant?

Comment: What is $w$? An integer?

Comment: Yes, w is integer, w>0

Comment: In the Fourier series it's $f_s$, not $f_i$. Do you want to compute the limit of the sum you wrote?